# CNC Servo System Grounding

Tags: grounding, shielding, controller, earth, cnc

Here it's a sketch of a simplified CNC servo system.
The servo drives are non isolated (Digital GND connected to Power GND, drawn as GND)
(My main question on the picture too)

#1: Why some manufacturers recommends connecting shield (for signal cables) to the Digital GND?

#2: What will happen if GND touches PE in some external device, of let's say USB going to the controller and that USB GND bounded to PE in the computer?

#3: Shield connection only on one end or both (also varies between manufacturers)

#4: What if one side of the power supply is grounded?

**Updated the sketch**

[image: MySketch]

Comment: Are all gnds at the same potential? If not, that’s when the problems start. As to what happens depends on the actual physical layout, so looking at a schematic only tells part of the story.

Comment: All GND (the black triangles) are on the same potential. This is how it recommended, but my question is what if the computer puts the GND to PE.

Answer (score 0):

1. If an earth ground is not available then using your system ground is the next best thing. The shields can't be left floating or they won't function as intended.
2. If the PE of your CNC machine and that of your PC are at a different potential, you'll have ground loop issues. This is very common. If you run into this, try a [USB isolator](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2107).
3. Shields should only be connected at one end. Preferably the lower impedance end. For example if you're using a star ground pattern, you want to ground the end closer to the hub.
4. While it may seem convenient to NOT connect your digital gnd to PE, in practice what will happen is that ~50V rms will be coupled into your digital ground and power buses as common mode noise. This tends to wreak havoc with sensors, especially thermocouples and capacitive sensors. There are various ways you can try to work around this, such as using a capacitor between PE and digital ground, but I would usually just start with digital ground connected to PE at 1 point.